# Browser showing question marks for other languages

Tags: php, sql, browser, unicode, phpmyadmin

I am extracting data from a MySQL database using a PHP script and my browser is Firefox Developer Edition.

When I see the database using phpmyadmin I can see  words in other languages without any problem but when they are displayed in my browser using my php script whole thing is a set of question marks

How can I fix this.
Please tell me what is the problem and how can I fix it.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. This is probably unicode characters that you are not encoding properly

Comment: You need to add charset in your html file

Comment: so what should i do

Comment: may be helpful https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_charset.asp

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Trouble with UTF-8 characters; what I see is not what I stored](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38363566/trouble-with-utf-8-characters-what-i-see-is-not-what-i-stored)

Comment: See "question mark" in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38363566/trouble-with-utf8-characters-what-i-see-is-not-what-i-stored